# How can I replicate the xtmg code from Stata in R

Tags: r, time, panel, stata, series

I have the below codes in Stata:

```
xtmg casepop l1casepop  l14casepop l7masksN d, robust
xtmg casepop l1casepop  l14casepop l14masksN d, robust
xtmg casepop l1casepop  l14casepop l28masksN d, robust
xtmg casepop l1casepop  l14casepop l42masksN d, robust
```

How can I replicate them in RStudio

Comment: R users who work with this kind of model would still be likely to appreciate some explanation of what the code does https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0246  The more specialised a procedure, the more likely it is that an exact equivalent does not exist so that you need to write R code yourself.

Comment: Hello Nick, thank you for your reply. I know that I have to write the code myself in R, however I don't know which code to use. Your help is much appreciated

Comment: Sorry, no, for several compelling reasons, starting with my not being an R programmer and not ever using this kind of model.  The bigger point is that the corresponding R code may be enormously longer. If there is an R equivalent that work should cite the same references.